# required HTML doesn't work on my web page

Tags: html, validation

I tried this in my code but the required function doesn't seem to work in my web page :

```
<div>
  <label for="Username">Username: </label>
  <input type="text" name="username" required>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it inside a form tag?

Comment: Shouldn't the value of `for` be another element's `id`, not name?

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a useful description of a problem. What do you expect it to do? What does it actually do?

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:javascript] and [tag:css]: I don't see any sign of either in the question.

Comment: Please elaborate more on what you are trying to accomplish, this will help us get a good picture of the problem you are facing at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input box is located within a `<form>` tag as intended, then `required` will work correctly in all modern browsers. Demo:

```html
<form>
<div>
  <label for="Username">Username: </label>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="Username" required>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="click to test"/>
</form>
```

Also `for=` on a label requires the target element to have an `id` with matching text before it's effective. It doesn't interact with the `name` attribute. I've added an id in the demo.

Answer (score 2):

For the "required" attribute to work, the `<input>` must be be wrapped in `<form> ... </form>` tags.